# Why IntelliJ is reporting "URI is not registered" and Attribute xsi: schemaLocation is not allowed here

Tags: maven, pom.xml

[image: screenshot of pom.xml]

IntelliJ is displaying two sets of errors ("URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schema and DTD)" & "Attribute xsi: schemaLocation is not allowed here") and has been unable to build. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same issue by:

1. Clich on the offending attribute.
2. Press `ALT+ENTER`.
3. Click on `Fetch external resource`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error disappeared after I changed HTTPS to HTTP like this.

```
- <project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
-   xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
+ <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
+   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

According to the official Maven docs only the .xsd URI seems to support HTTPS. See https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_Basics